# Как получить разметку XML от объекта fragment?

Tags: android

В продолжении нашего разговора.

Мы получили фрагмент.

```
Fragment fragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(position);
```

Получили класс вот этого фрагмента

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artist_fragment,null);

        return v;
    }

}
```

как мне в fragment получить его разметку и работать непосредственно с элементами фрагмента в главном активити?

Comment: Желательно всю работу с элементами оставить во фрагменте, а из активити дергать только нужные методы фрагмента, иначе инкапсуляция логики во фрагмент теряет смысл

Comment: т.е. в фрагменте мне подключиться к серверу, заполнить данные а потом вернуть в активити?

Comment: Нет, обращение к серверу и получение данных лучше реализовать в активити, а вот присвоение этих данных компонентам фрагмента лучше делать через дергание методов, реализованных во фрагменте, например: fragment.setFirstTextViewText("some text"); а не получать доступ к TextView в активити, и там уже присваивать значение. Вам самому будет нагляднее работать с такой структурой, когда логика работы с компонентами вынесена в отдельный класс

Comment: ооо прикольно щас попробую,!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно выделить два сценария передачи данных из Activity во фрагмент:

1. Вы передаёте набор данных во фрагмент при его создании. Это лучше всего делать упаковав данные в Bundle и подключив их к фрагменту методом setArguments(). При инициализации фрагмента вы достаёте эти данные методом getArguments() и визуализиурете их уже внутри фрагмента;
2. Вам нужно передать какие-то данные уже тогда, когда фрагмент был создан ранее. В этом случае, берите объект фрагмента, в котором предварительно реализованы публичные методы-сеттеры для обработки поступающих данных. Например, у вас есть TextView, в котором вы хотите отобразить переданный с Activity текст. Вы пишете внутри фрагмента публичный метод setNewText(String text), внутри которого вызываете setText(String text) на ваш TextView. Когда у вас в руках окажется объект фрагмента нужного класса, вы сможете вызвать setNewText(String text) на нём и передать текст во фрагмент, а он там отобразится.

Не перемешивайте логику. Всё что внутри фрагмента - должно оставаться внутри фрагмента. И наоборот.

Answer (score -1):

сделайте свойство View и get метод для него, и обращайтесь непосредственно к View

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
   View view;

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artist_fragment,null);
       this.view = v;
       return v;
   }

   public View getView(){
       return this.view;
   }
```

}

Comment: Что то не работает(( возвращает null

Comment: Вы рассказываете человеку, как сделать то, что он хочет, при этом умалчивая о том, что так делать нельзя. Между фрагментом и активити должны исключительно данные ходить и в редких случаях вызовы через интерфейсы. А работа с View и визуализация поступивших данных только во фрагменте!

Comment: + у фрагмента  есть аналогичный метод getView()

Comment: и что за дефолтный модификатор у параметра