# Получить экземпляр Fragment в activity.onСreate()?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть такая проблема, подключаю `ViewPager`.
Работает все нормально, но мне надо что бы в `Activity.onCreate()` я получил экземпляр первого активити и присвоил значение `TextView` в фрагменте.

Вот что я делаю:

**Фрагмент:**

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
    TextView textView;




    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artist_fragment,null);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return v;
    }


    public void setTextTextView(String text){
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
        Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();
        frag1.setTextTextView("Текст");
}
```

После отладки я вижу что `frag1` и все его элементы `null`. Он получает ссылку на `frag1`, но все параметры по `null`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам уже говорили что так делать плохо

Comment: Всмысле? мне наоборот так подсказали, что бы я из Активити обращался к фрагментам через методы!

Comment: внимательно почитайте - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/449104/189466

Comment: это про вот это строчки - Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();
        frag1.setTextTextView("Текст")

Comment: в упор не вижу что вы имеете в виду, мне все советуют передавать значение из активити во фрагмент

Comment: у вас логика которая выставляет текст в TextView должна во фрагменте быть

Comment: Первый ответ из предыдущего вопроса: Вы пишете внутри фрагмента публичный метод setNewText(String text), внутри которого вызываете setText(String text) на ваш TextView. Когда у вас в руках окажется объект фрагмента нужного класса, вы сможете вызвать setNewText(String text) на нём и передать текст во фрагмент, а он там отобразится.

Comment: Второй ответ из предыдущего вороса обращение к серверу и получение данных лучше реализовать в активити, а вот присвоение этих данных компонентам фрагмента лучше делать через дергание методов, реализованных во фрагменте, например: fragment.setFirstTextViewText("some text"); а не получать доступ к TextView в активити, и там уже присваивать значение.

Comment: Эти ответы неверные?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28884/discussion-between-s-klepcha-and-duddeniska).

Comment: Блин уезжать надо, есть скайп? буду раде если поможете за денежное вознаграждение! я за грамотный код!

Comment: первый ответ плохое решение, второй - в правильным направлении. Фрагменты для того и созданны что бы брать на себя очень большую часть взаимодействий с пользователем у активити. Пересмотрите своё решение согласно которому вы данные получаете в активити и передаёте в фрагмент. И при инициализации фрагмента передавайте ему необходимые объекты для получения данных. А логику работы с этими данными реализуйте во фрагменте

Comment: со скайпом не помогу - работа, знаете ли, не поймут

Comment: в активити открываете соеденение и из каждого фрагмента еог дёргаете - видимый в конкретное время фрагмент должен по своему распорядиться с данными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компонент ViewPager работает немного по другому, присваивать данные в самом вызывающем акивити не стоит, их нужно передавать в адаптере, а потом присваивать методом `viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);` Хороший пример [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html), разберись, все методы присваивания инкапсулированы в классе `PagerAdapter`

Comment: пример классный, но у меня три разных fragmenta, а там в примере один!

Comment: @duddeniska какая разница? либо передавайте фрагменты в адаптер в качестве параметров, либо прям внутри их создаватйе

Comment: Обратите внимание на переопределенный метод getItem(int position), который и возвращает фрагмент, который будет отображаться в ViewPager. Поэтому это уже на ваше усмотрение

Answer (score 0):

Как я вижу фрагмент просто не отображен нужно добавить

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
    Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout, frag).commit();
    frag1.setTextTextView("Текст");
}
```

Comment: R.id.frame_layout, - это что за шаблон?

Comment: в layout Activity нужно добавить FrameLayout (это что то вроде Relative layout) таким образом чтобы он находился поверх всех элементов, также нужно добавить id для FrameLayout  в данном случае frame_layout